# Blocking External Mail Sent w/ Spoofed Email Address

Tags: email, sendmail, spam, spoofing

We recently got an email from an outside server that had a spoofed "From:" header that was the email address of one of our users.  Is there a way to have sendmail reject emails coming in from an outside network that claim to be a specfic user, but still allow that user to send mail from our own servers?  How can I set this up?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) or [DomainKeys Identified Mail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail). And configure sendmail to verify SPF and DomainKeys. This will reduce some of your received spam too.